# Best Practices for storing passwords in Ruby. Xml, source or other?

Tags: ruby, xml, passwords, base64

I have a Ruby script that sends an email, but I need to store the smtp account credentials in order for the email to get sent. Currently, I have an xml file that I'm storing the password in, however I'm encoding the password using Bas64 in the xml and then decoding in my script. I packaged the script into an .exe as well.

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is in terms of storing credentials. Should I be storing the password in the actual script instead of the xml? Is there some other method that I should be using? The script isn't going to be running on a server that's exposed outside of the LAN, but I'd still like to make sure that the password is as secure as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is not encryption, anyone can reverse it.  For that matter, using actual encryption isn't going to help if your program contains the key and is itself readable.  If you need to write a program that uses a password, but you do not want the password accessible to users of the program, you will need to use the operating system as well as code.

1. Put the password into a separate file from the code.
2. Use the operating system's access control for files to make sure only people who are allowed to can read the file with the password.  This is not the same list as people who can run the program, and may only be the administrator.
3. Add a pseudo-user to the operating system for the script. This is not a real person, but an account that only the program will use in order to run.  Add this user to the access control for the file with the password such that it can read the file.  Make sure this user cannot login interactively, e.g. obtain a shell prompt or get a desktop session.
4. Enable the people you want to run the program to run the program "as" the pseudo-user for the script.  In Windows this can be done with the "runas" command.  On Linux you can use "sudo".